# C# 7.0 Какой алгоритм сортировки реализован в Sort()

Tags: c#, .net, сортировка

До Net.framework 4 использовалась быстрая сортировка QuickSort, какой алгоритм используется в Net.Framework 4.5+?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По документации - До 4.5 использовалась быстрая сортировка. Судя по коду - на самом деле использовался QuickSort + пирамидальная на глубине рекурсии больше 32.

[В 4.5 и более поздних](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.0-4.6.2#listsort-algorithm-changed) (включая core) используется [Introsort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) - гибрид быстрой, сортировки простыми вставками (на коротких диапазонах) и пирамидальной (на определенной глубине рекурсии).

В CoreCLR, судя по всему, используется тот же Introsort, что и в 4.5+, но реализация переписана на плюсах.

- [Код сортировки до 4.5](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/arraysorthelper.cs,237)
- [Код сортировки в 4.5+](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/arraysorthelper.cs,308)
- [Код сортировки в CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/ab2f9caaf35c96d029b96aa171ee65d04253cf7c/src/classlibnative/bcltype/arrayhelpers.h#L155)